# Correspondence between $(\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (S^1 \times S^1, x_0)$ and $(\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2,(0,0))$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, algebraic-topology

Let $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ be the standard universal covering map of the torus. Let $x_o=p(0,0).$ Suppose $q \in \mathbb{R}P^2$. Show that composition with $p$ induces a one-to-one correspondence between continuous maps $(\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (S^1 \times S^1, x_0)$ and continuous maps $(\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2,(0,0))$

My proof feels like it is missing something... I have shown that given a map from one of these sets, it has a canonical way to persribe it a map in the other set. I'm not sure if I have completely and rigourously answered the question, can somebody help me out? Thanks!

---

$Proof:$

Every map  $f: (\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (S^1 \times S^1, x_0)$ has a unique lift $\tilde{f}: (\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2,(0,0))$ such that $p\tilde{f}=f$.

Also, starting with a map $g: (\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2,(0,0))$, we have that $pg$ is a map from $(\mathbb{R}P^2,q) \rightarrow (S^1 \times S^1, x_0)$.

Comment: Your answer isn't quite complete.  You need to show that the correspondence $f \mapsto \tilde{f}$ is bijective -- or, instead, that the correspondence $g \mapsto p \circ g$ is bijective.  You could do this by showing that the two correspondences are inverse to each other: so, if you do one followed by the other, you get the original map back.  In other words, check that $p \circ \widetilde{f} = f$ and $\widetilde{p \circ g} = g$.  (Warning: I haven't actually checked that $p \circ \widetilde{f} = f$ and $\widetilde{p \circ g} = g$ are true.  I'm simply saying what ought to be done.)

Comment: Starting with $f: \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$, we lift this map to $\tilde{f}$, which we can do since the lifting criterion has been met, thus we have a map $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Now, since $p\tilde{f}=f$, by composing $p$ with $\tilde{f}$ we once again get a map from $\mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$. Thus these two sets are in bijective correspondence with eachother.

Is this correct?